# Postgresql How extract date

Tags: postgresql

I need get only the date from now() at my time zone, I have this query:

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'
```

And I'm getting something like this "2015-06-08 23:59:34.142569"
but I need extract only the date, how can I get it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the server's date,

```
SELECT current_date;
```

If you need the date for any timestamp, eg the one you've gotten into your timezone, use `date()`.

```
SELECT date(now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago');
```

Docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the better doc link, @a_horse_with_no_name!

Answer (score 0):

For postgres you want

```
select current_date;
```

if you need to extract any of those fields out of the returned value you can use extract

```
EXTRACT (field FROM source)
```